# Can snowflake work as an operational data store against which I can write rest APIs

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am researching snowflake database and have a data aggregation use case, where i need to expose the aggregated data via a Rest API.  While the data ingestion and aggregation seems to be well defined, is snowflake a system that can be used as an operational data store for servicing high throughput apis?
Or is this an anti pattern for this system

Comment: Do you want to read and write transactions to Snowflake through the Rest API, or just run aggregation queries in Snowflake?

Comment: Run aggregate queries read out the result set

Comment: I have done the same exact thing on snowflake with great success. I was initially using aws RDS but with the data volume it simply was not working where as with snowflake it was really fast. Also remember its a columnar database design. So if you have fewer aggregated columns better. Also another big part to think is the warehouse type depending on your volume.

Comment: Snowflake is excellent at this use-case because of its elasticity and near endless concurrency.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any query timing results that you could share?

Answer (score 0):

Updating based on your recent comment.

Here's some quick test results I did on large tables we have in production. *Changed the table names for display.

vLookupView records = 175,760,316

vMainView records = 179,035,026

```
SELECT 
    LP.REGIONCODE
    , SUM(L.VALUE)    
FROM DBO.vLookupView AS LP
INNER JOIN DBO.vMainView AS M
    ON LP.PK = M.PK
GROUP BY LP.REGIONCODE;
```

**Results:**

```
SQL SERVER 
Production box - 2:04 minutes
**Snowflake:**
By Warehouse (compute) size
XS - 17.1 seconds
Small - 9.9 seconds
Medium - 7.1s seconds
Large - 5.4 seconds
Extra Large - 5.4 seconds
```

When I added a WHERE condition

```
WHERE L.ENTEREDDATE BETWEEN '1/1/2018' AND '6/1/2018'
```

the results were:

```
SQL SERVER 
Production box - 5 seconds
**Snowflake:**
By Warehouse (compute) size
XS - 12.1 seconds
Small - 3.9 seconds
Medium - 3.1s seconds
Large - 3.1 seconds
Extra Large - 3.1 seconds
```

Comment: I am looking more around a data read kind of scenario vs data load/ingest. If i have data across multiple tables within the warehouse and i am doing joins via views, is it performant enough to do point look ups on the joined data? and if you have any timing results you can share that would be great

Comment: @vmurthy Added some quick test results I can share. If it was helpful please consider marking as the answer, otherwise if you have something more specific I can share some other test results.

Comment: this is great. Thank you so much for this data. Do you have any results which show what the performance looks like as the number of joins increases for example